# matplotlib: hide subplot and fill space with other subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got a figure that contains three subplots which are arranged vertically. Once I click into the figure, I want the second subplot `ax2` to be hidden and the other plots to fill the space. A second click into the figure should restore the original plot and layout.

Hiding the subplot `ax2` isn't a problem, but how can I rearrange the positions of the other subplots?

I've tried creating a new `GridSpec`, using the `set_position` and `set_subplotspec` methods, but nothing worked out. I'm sure I'm missing something here, any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[5, 2, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2], sharex=ax2)

visible = True

def toggle_ax2(event):
    global visible
    visible = not visible
    ax2.set_visible(visible)
    plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', toggle_ax2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define two different `GridSpec`s. One would have 3 subplots, the other 2. Depending on the visibility of the middle axes, you change the position of the other two axes to obey to the first or second GridSpec.
(There is no need for any dummy figure or so, like other answers might suggest.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[5, 2, 1], hspace=0.3)
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(2,1, height_ratios=[5,3])

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2], sharex=ax2)

ax1.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], color="crimson")
ax2.plot([1,2,3], [2,3,1], color="darkorange")
ax3.plot([1,2,3], [3,2,1], color="limegreen")

visible = True

def toggle_ax2(event):
    global visible
    visible = not visible
    ax2.set_visible(visible)
    if visible:
        ax1.set_position(gs[0].get_position(fig))
        ax3.set_position(gs[2].get_position(fig))
    else:
        ax1.set_position(gs2[0].get_position(fig))
        ax3.set_position(gs2[1].get_position(fig))

    plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', toggle_ax2)
plt.show()
```

Left: original; right: after clicking

[image]

Comment: What happens if you have five axes?… Do you need a different `gridspec` for 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 axes showing? To make matters more complicated, some of those axes must be bigger than others…

Comment: @Sardathrion It all depends on what exactly you want to do. Just having five axes but still wanting to toggle only one of them you would still need only two gridspecs. But wanting to be able to toggle them all, a large number of gridspec may be used in case all possible combinations should then have different height ratios. However, I would recommend to rather take a single gridspec and manipulate its properites on the fly instead.

Comment: @Sardathrion Sorry, that was not what I meant. If you have 5 subplots and you want to be able to toggle them all, you still need 5 gridspecs, one with 5 rows, one with 4 rows etc. But you can update the `height_ratios` on the fly to produce the layout of choice for each of them.

Comment: Right. I grok it now. Thank you. ☺

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `gridspec` instance, and use that to create some dummy figures in a second figure (you can close this before you `plt.show`, so you never actually see it, we just want to grab some positions from the axes here).

By storing the two possible positions for `ax1` and `ax3` from that dummy figure and the original figure, then you can use `ax.set_position()` in your `toggle_ax2` function to change the positions of the remaining two axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[5, 2, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1], sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2], sharex=ax2)

# Store the original positions of ax1 and ax3
pos1_1 = ax1.get_position()
pos3_1 = ax3.get_position()

# Create a second gridspec for when ax2 is hidden. Keep 5:1 ratio
gs2 = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[5, 1])
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax1_2 = fig2.add_subplot(gs2[0])
ax3_2 = fig2.add_subplot(gs2[1])

# Store the positions of ax1 and ax3 in the new gridspec
pos1_2 = ax1_2.get_position()
pos3_2 = ax3_2.get_position()

# Close the dummy figure2
plt.close(fig2)

visible = True

def toggle_ax2(event):
    global visible

    visible = not visible
    ax2.set_visible(visible)

    # Use the stored positions to switch between 
    # different arrangements of ax1 and ax3
    if visible:
        ax1.set_position(pos1_1)
        ax3.set_position(pos3_1)
    else:
        ax1.set_position(pos1_2)
        ax3.set_position(pos3_2)
    plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', toggle_ax2)
plt.show()
```

Original configuration:
[image]

After removing `ax2`:
[image]