# Matplotlib get subplot (axes) size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Just wandering - how can one obtain the size of a subplot (axes?) in Matplotlib?

If I do Ctrl-F "size" in https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html - there is only one match, in context: "... with varying marker size and/or  ...", so it does not really tell me how to find the size of the axes.

Say, I have the same code as in [Interactively resize figure and toggle plot visibility in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978319/interactively-resize-figure-and-toggle-plot-visibility-in-matplotlib)

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib
print("matplotlib.__version__ {}".format(matplotlib.__version__))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

default_size_inch = (9, 6)
showThird = False

def onpress(event):
  global fig, ax1, ax2, ax3, showThird
  if event.key == 'x':
    showThird = not showThird
    if showThird:
      fig.set_size_inches(default_size_inch[0]+3, default_size_inch[1], forward=True)
      plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.85) # leave a bit of space on the right
      ax3.set_visible(True)
      ax3.set_axis_on()
    else:
      fig.set_size_inches(default_size_inch[0], default_size_inch[1], forward=True)
      plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.9) # default
      ax3.set_visible(False)
      ax3.set_axis_off()
    fig.canvas.draw()


def main():
  global fig, ax1, ax2, ax3
  xdata = np.arange(0, 101, 1) # 0 to 100, both included
  ydata1 = np.sin(0.01*xdata*np.pi/2)
  ydata2 = 10*np.sin(0.01*xdata*np.pi/4)

  fig = plt.figure(figsize=default_size_inch, dpi=120)
  ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
  ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,0), colspan=2, sharex=ax1)
  ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,2), rowspan=3)

  ax3.set_visible(False)
  ax3.set_axis_off()

  ax1.plot(xdata, ydata1, color="Red")
  ax2.plot(xdata, ydata2, color="Khaki")

  fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', lambda event: onpress(event))
  plt.show()


# ENTRY POINT
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

How do I find the size of the subplots represented by ax1 and ax2 axes?

Comment: Matplotlib figures have [many coordinate systems](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). In which coordinate system would you like to know the size of the axis?

Comment: Thanks @PaulBrodersen - I guess, I'd want both the "relative" (i.e. `"figure"`) and the "absolute" (that is, `"figure-inches"`) in terms of Figure, as I'd like to have that info for further scaling/resizing of the subplots.

Comment: `ax.get_position()` gives the position in relative figure coordinates. Divide those numbers by the figure size in inches (`fig.get_size_inches()`) to get the position in inches.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306510/determine-matplotlib-axis-size-in-pixels Does this help?

Answer (score 4):

For the full explanation of how `bbox` works refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809238/definition-of-matplotlib-pyplot-axes-bbox). Each of your axes object fits in a bounding box. All you need to do is to get the height and width of your axis bounding box.
`ax_h, ax_w = ax.bbox.height, ax.bbox.width`

You can transform to figure coordinates by using `bbox.transformed` method. For example:
`ax_h = ax.bbox.transformed(fig.gca().transAxes).height`

Comment: Please give an explanation of how your answer works and what exactly you have done. This encourages OP to copy and paste, without understanding what the solution was.