# Where can I find documentation on AxesSubplot in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

In looking for answer to [Matplotlib get subplot (axes) size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992207/matplotlib-get-subplot-axes-size) ,  I've realized that the `ax1`, `ax2` variables there are of class `AxesSubplot`.

However, I cannot find any documentation on this anywhere - for instance:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/search.html?q=axessubplot&check_keywords=yes&area=default

results with:

> Your search did not match any documents

So, is `AxesSubplot` class properties and methods documented anywhere; and if not, which is the right source file to consult, to find its API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `AxesSubplot` is an object that is created on the fly when creating subplots in matplotlib. It hence has no documentation. But for most practical purposes it's identical to the usual [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=axes#matplotlib.axes.Axes).

In addition it has methods of [`SubplotBase`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.SubplotBase.html) available.

Comment: Many thanks, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - great to have this documented. That was my first guess too, but I saw the `Axes` page has `position` under "Other optional keyword arguments", and I tried to print `ax1.position`, and got `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'position'` - which confused me, and is the reason why I ended up asking this question.

Comment: Yes, if `position` is an "optional keyword argument", it means `Axes(..., position=...)` is valid. If you click on that you are directed to the method: `ax.set_position` (equally you can use `ax.get_position`).